# What is the inside of a bracket called?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

Here's maybe a simple question about nomenclature.

Is there a formal name for the *inside of a bracket*:

$$\left(\Large\text{ inside }\right)$$

in the same manner that parts and terms in usual arithmetic procedures always have clear names.

Comment: very philosophically if you think about brackets as an identity function you can call it an argument, but I believe it would sound weird. anyway, I've never hear a name to what is inside the brackets

Comment: In $(a+b)\cdot c$ we'd refer to $a+b$ as "the first factor". There are rare situations where we'd really want to / need to distinguish between $a+b$ and $(a+b)$, hence I doubt the introduction of a special name would be advantageous - it might take longer to explain it than what you save afterward by the "many" uses

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a totally okay question IMO

Comment: It's called "the inside of the bracket" or "what is between the brackets". There's no special name.

Comment: Since the purpose of the bracket-set is to ensure that its contents are treated as a group, why not just call its contents the group?

Comment: "Content"?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enclosed expression** is a term commonly used in programming. It's perfectly clear, although a little long.